# Universal ImageLoader doesn't display full image

Tags: android, universal-image-loader

I am trying to show an image in an ImageView with Universal ImageLoader but only part of the image is shown. It's like it's zoomed in for some reason.

```
public class Image extends Activity {

    ImageView iv;
    protected ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
    DisplayImageOptions options;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.image);

        iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

        options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
           .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.noimage)
           .cacheOnDisc(true)
           .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.EXACTLY_STRETCHED)
           .cacheInMemory(true)
           .bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565)
           .displayer(new RoundedBitmapDisplayer(0))
           .build();

        if (!imageLoader.isInited()) {
            initImageLoader();
        }

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String image = intent.getStringExtra("image");
        Log.i("Image", "" + image);
        if (image != null) {
            imageLoader.displayImage("https://www.example.com/"+image, iv, options);
        }

    }

    private void initImageLoader() {
        int memoryCacheSize;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ECLAIR) {
            int memClass = ((ActivityManager) 
                    this.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE))
                    .getMemoryClass();
            memoryCacheSize = (memClass / 8) * 1024 * 1024;
        } else {
            memoryCacheSize = 2 * 1024 * 1024;
        }

        final ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(
                this).threadPoolSize(5)
                .threadPriority(Thread.NORM_PRIORITY - 2)
                .memoryCacheSize(memoryCacheSize)
                //.memoryCache(new FIFOLimitedMemoryCache(memoryCacheSize-1000000))
                .denyCacheImageMultipleSizesInMemory()
                .discCacheFileNameGenerator(new Md5FileNameGenerator())
                .build();

        ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config);
    }

}
```

Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#000000" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

</LinearLayout>
```

That's the whole activity, no code was left out.

[image]

Comment: android:scaleType="fitCenter"

Comment: @NOSTRA As I recommended,but erdomester said its not working,If any other solution then please post it.

Comment: Hi @NOSTRA I am still unable to make it work. I included a few examples of the settings.

Comment: Try to no use `.imageScaleType(...)`.

Comment: The solution was to comment out .displayer(new RoundedBitmapDisplayer(0)) line!

Comment: i have this issue still , can someone tell me what to change, i dont have the displayer line in options

Answer (score 2):

Some setting must be wrong with   `.displayer(new RoundedBitmapDisplayer(0))` because it is what caused the error. Setting the round value to 0 was not enough, I had to remove this line in order to display the image in the correct form.

Comment: This worked. Replaced the 'new' block with 'new FadeInBitmapDisplayer(300)' instead.

Answer (score 0):

To fit image in `ImageView`,Change

```
 .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.EXACTLY_STRETCHED)
```

to

```
.imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.EXACTLY)
```

And in your xml layout

change

```
   android:scaleType="centerCrop"
```

to

```
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
```

Comment: I tried but it gives me a rather strange effect. It displays the image in small and pulls down the bottom if to the bottom of the screen